# ¿Se pude pasar de un código en C a lenguaje ensamblador?

Tags: c

¿Cómo puedo llevar mi código de C a ensamblador?
¿Existe alguna herramienta en línea para convertirlo a "lenguaje ensamblador"?

Comment: Esto talvez te pueda servir https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26091622/convert-c-program-into-assembly-code

Comment: Te damos la Bienvenida a StackOverflow en Español. Te invito a que pases por el [Recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leas el artículo [Cómo Preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea bien recibida.

Answer (score 4):

Prueba la opción `-S` de `gcc`. De la ayuda de `gcc` obtenida de `gcc --help`:

```
user@hostname:~ $ gcc --help
Usage: gcc [options] file...
Options:
...
-S   Compile only; do not assemble or link
```

Si prefieres el lenguaje ensamblador de Intel en lugar del de AT&T que viene por defecto (el nombre de algunas directivas de ensamblador son diferentes entre uno y otro), debes añadir la opción `-masm=intel` al comando de `gcc`:

```
gcc -S -masm=intel miarchivo.c -o miarchivo.asm
```

Answer (score 1):

¡Hola! Si podes, es mas, siempre que dev, codeblocks o lo que uses compila el programa lo pasa a lenguaje de maquina, si ellos pueden es porque alguien le explico como hacerlo

https://godbolt.org/ Esta pagina convierte codigo de `C++` en `assembly`, no se la parte del main ¡pero todas las funciones pasadas a nivel bajo representarian lo mismo que en `C`!

Comment: el gotbolt, a mi no me ha funcionado